# how to reduced large correlation matrix

Tags: r, bioinformatics, correlation

I have a very large (10000x10000) correlation matrix and would like to show it in the heatmap.  I think it is not possible to do so that want to reduced the matrix with some threshold values.

```
    cellA <- data.frame(rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1), 
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1),
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1), 
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1),
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1), 
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1),
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1), 
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1), 
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1),
                        rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=1))
    row.names(cellA) <- paste("G_", 1:10000)
    colnames(cellA) <- paste("M_", 1:10)
    corr <- cor(t(cellA))
    threshold <- 0.6
    gene.corrlation <- corr
    diag(gene.corrlation) <- 0
    sig.corr <- apply(abs(gene.corrlation) >= threshold, 1, any)
    filter.corr.gene <- corr[sig.corr, sig.corr]
```

**I would like assistance understanding how I can able to get values higher than 0.6.**

Comment: What is the expected output? Your current solution works fine?

Comment: Agree with @zx8754, if you want it to be more efficient, try to swap out your `apply()` statement for `colSums(abs(gene.corrlation) >= threshold) > 0` to create your index